# How to truncate address in c

Tags: c

Im writing a hexdump function in C.

How can I truncate a given address (void* start) to the greatest multiple of 16 that's less than the given start argument? 
Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Something like `(uintptr_t) start & ~0xfU`?

Comment: Less, or less-or-equal? What do you want for an address `0x123F0` that already ends with four zero bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uintptr_t rounded = ((uintptr_t)start) & ~0xF;
```

Comment: The best solution. *Strictly* reading the OP's question, you should probably need `(((uintptr_t)start) - 1) & ~0x0F` (ah -- would one need to cast `start` to a char type before bluntly subtracting 1?)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `void *address` contains your original address:

```
unsigned long int multiple =  (unsigned long int)address/16;
void *new_address = (void*)(16 * multiple;)
```

Dividing by 16 will give you the integral value.

Comment: @user2817587, I suggest you use this but not with 'int'. Use unsigned long instead. Addresses are always unsigned and this conversion will most likely result in a wrong address. In C++ you would use size_t.

Answer (score 0):

```
uintptr_t x = ((uintptr_t)addr) & ~((1 << 4) - 1);
```

Note that a uintptr_t (from C99) is an unsigned integer guaranteed large enough to hold a pointer on your platform.

The bit shifting zeros the lowest 4 bits (so multiples of 16).